# SerializationException connecting to AVRO Schema Registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have 4 consumers 3 are on version 0.10.0.0 of the kafka-client but one has moved to version 2.0.0

When I call RestService.getId to get a version of my AVRO schema it succeeds on the three consumers who are on the early version, but fails on the 2.0.0 version, with this stack trace.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 18
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:185)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:229)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:409)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:402)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:119)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:192)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:168)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:121)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:104)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:62)
    at com.ciscospark.retention.kafkapurgelibrary.avro.deserialize.CompatibleAvroDeserializer.deserialize(CompatibleAvroDeserializer.java:48)
    at com.ciscospark.retention.kafkapurgelibrary.avro.deserialize.CompatibleAvroDeserializer.deserialize(CompatibleAvroDeserializer.java:19)
    at com.cisco.wx2.kafka.serialization.SparkKafkaDeserializer.deserialize(SparkKafkaDeserializer.java:34)
    at com.ciscospark.retention.kafkapurgelibrary.PurgeEventConsumerFactory.lambda$new$1(PurgeEventConsumerFactory.java:80)
    at com.cisco.wx2.kafka.serialization.SimpleKafkaDeserializer.deserialize(SimpleKafkaDeserializer.java:22)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1009)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:96)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1186)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1500(Fetcher.java:1035)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:505)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1259)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1187)
```

Here is my code that created the connection to the schema registry.  It uses a URL beginning in https

```
    private RestService getSchemaServiceRestService() {
        String avroSchemaRegistryUrl = this.getAvroSchemaRegistryUrl;
        RestService restService = new RestService(avroSchemaRegistryUrl);
        log.info("Avro schema registry URL {}", avroSchemaRegistryUrl);

        if (avroSchemaRegistryUrl.startsWith("https")) {
            SSLContext sslContext = null;
            try {
                sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                        .loadKeyMaterial(AvroSerializer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("avroSchemaRegistryClient.jks"),
                                avroSchemaRegistryKeyPass.toCharArray(),
                                avroSchemaRegistryKeyPass.toCharArray())
                        .loadTrustMaterial(AvroSerializer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("avroSchemaRegistryServer.jks"),
                                avroSchemaRegistryKeyPass.toCharArray())
                        .build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception when creating sslContext for schema registry client");
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception when creating sslContext for schema registry client.", e);
            }

            SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            restService.setSslSocketFactory(factory);
            log.info("Configured SSL for schema registry client");
        }

        return restService;
    }
```

This function succeeds but when I make the first call to RestService.getId I get that exception.

Anyone have any idea how I can get my version 2.0.0 consumer to work?

Comment: If its any help I am seeing this in the logs at the avro schema registery

2019/11/05 16:37:54 [info] 17529#0: *17966136 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 52.14.5.177, server: 0.0.0.0:8082

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need to write your own deserializer

Comment: Are you saying that if we used the vanilla deserializer we would not be seeing this issue when doing the handshake with the schema regisrty:   SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol

Comment: I'm saying that `RestService` and `CachedSchemaRegistryClient` should already support SSL out of the box, so you shouldn't need to wrap them in something else.

Comment: Also, there is no "version 2.0.0" of the schema registry client, so which version of it are you using?

Comment: I am usng schema registry client 4.1.1. and the Kafka client 2.0.0.     I need to find out what version my Schema registry server is running at though.

Comment: Might want to upgrade the client since I believe Confluent 5.0 is for Kafka 2.0

Comment: Does this seem broken.  kafka-schema-registry-4.0.3. kafka-client 2.0.0  as they don't seem to be working for me.

Comment: As I mentioned, I would ensure you're using matching client versions based on the Confluent release notes and that the client matches the server version

Comment: One of our services was hardcoding TLSv1 into its startup config, and this was not compatible with out schema registry version which was expecting TLSv1.2.  We removed the hardcoded TLSv1 redeployed and it now works.  Thanks cricket_007

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below with the solution